# Mongodb - updateOne changes filetype and overwrites other data while using java in jmeter

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter

I'm using jMeter in my performance testing and need to change some data in document in mongodb. I've run into a problem, where while using updateOne command, translating working mongosh query into java, the behavior in jmeter/java is different.

My field which needs to be changed is nested inside object, which is inside array, which is inside object (image 1).

[image 1: Data structure as seen in MongoDBCompass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9OuW.png)

I need to change value of 'number' field to value of one of my jmeter values. In mongodbcompass it works perfectly when I use script like this:

```
db.process.updateOne({_id: "01deda7ec9894a3cbdeb"},
      {$set: {
        "individualPerson.identityDocuments.0.number": "ZZA002204"
      }}

    )
```

But while using this java code inside jmeter (java/groovy) overwrites everything in Object "0" and changes data type of individualPerson from Array to Object (image 2)

(collection is name for variable, which points to proccess collection)

```
collection.updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", 01deda7ec9894a3cbdeb), Updates.set("individualPerson.identityDocuments.0.number", "abc123456")
```

[image 2: Data after changing it with jmeter/java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzvap.png)

What can be done to change it properly while using jmeter?

I've tried passing java array into updateone method, but it didn't update anything.
I've also tried sending mongosh query to mongodb using java, but it also didn't work

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

You should try a filter first and use the updated document to override, something like this

```
Document filter = new Document("_id", "01deda7ec9894a3cbdeb");

Document update = new Document("$set", new Document("individualPerson.identityDocuments.0.number", "abc123456"));

collection.updateOne(filter, update);
```